# Is there any API to create and delete Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail-api

I'm seeking for APIs to create new Gmail IDs and then delete them after a period of time; can someone advise me if there are any available?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if you are using a Google Workspace account. You can create and delete users using the directory API and the [users.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert) and [users.delete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/delete) methods. This does not apply for free Gmail accounts as there is no API to create or delete free Gmail accounts.